# How to use string.len() function inside f-string formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, f-string

How do I get `len()` to work inside Python f-string formatting?

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    (f'{key:<(len(key)+2)}<->{value:>4}\n')
```

Comment: @zvone: Yes for this particular example len() can be avoided, but in the general case it can't and this question is useful.

Comment: @smci you are commenting on my comment... but my answer below actually shows how to fix it in general case as well.

Comment: @zvone: fine, then all these comments can be deleted as no longer needed. Can you edit your answer so that the context "key left-aligned in space which is by two larger than the length of the key"? It sounds excessively specific if this answer is to stand for the general case of the syntax for using len() inside an f-string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, you want to write `key` left-aligned in a field of length two larger than the length of `key` itself:

```
f'{key:<(len(key)+2)}'  # wrong syntax, copied from the question
```

... assuming that `key` is a string, that can be done more simply by adding two spaces after `key`:

```
f'{key}  '
```

In the general case (where `key` is not necessarily a string), do this:

```
f'{key:<{len(key)+2}}'  # correct syntax
```